# Is there any way to put range of numbers in a list that the difference of each number is more than x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, for-loop

I'm writing a code to takes two inputs n and k.
n is the maximum range of our number.
k is the minimum value that we want to use to put n numbers together.
If you couldn't understand pay attention to:
The code gets two inputs n and k:

```
n, k = [int(a) for a in input().split()]
```

For example n = 5 and k = 2.
I want to sort the numbers from 1 to 5(n) that their difference between each two of them is equals of more than 2(k) and if the condition is not suitable for our n print "Impossible".
For example if n = 2 and k = 2 , then their difference will be less than 2(k) anyway.

I wrote this:

```
n, k = [int(a) for a in input().split()]
list = []
for i in range(n+1, 1):
    if i - (i-2) >= k:
        list.append(i)
        print(list)

    elif n <= k:
        print("Impossible")
```

What I want is this:
For example if n = 5 and k = 2,
the output should be:

```
1 4 2 5 3
```

and for n = 2 and k = 2:

```
Impossible
```

But its not working I'm so confused is there any function or anything that can help me in this?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Your loop `for i in range(n+1, 1):` is never executed. Please check how `range` function works. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#range

Answer (score 1):

Your code "doesn't work" because your `if` statement doesn't do anything useful:

```
if i - (i-2) >= k:
```

Do the algebra to simplify this:

```
if 2 >= k:
```

This merely tests the input value several times.

Work with pencil and paper for a bit.  How can you arrange the numbers from 1 to n such that the *least* difference will be as large as possible?  Look at the example you posted earlier: what is the pattern there?  Extend it for, say, 8 and 9 numbers.

Find that pattern.  That one, general solution will lead you immediately to a solution where possible, and "impossible" for everything else.

Another possibility is to try all possible arrangements (use `itertools.permutation`) and check them all for a solution.

Third is to generate solutions, backtracking when you hit a dead-end.  This requires a little extra work to learn recursion, or to get the same effect with iteration.

Does that get you going?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how itertools.permutations works?

Comment: Can give me an example of itertools.permutations ??

Comment: Looking up tutorial information is your responsibility.  Please repeat the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).    Stack Overflow is not intended as a replacement for existing tutorials.